# Does the original Github repository also have the issue if I open an issue in a forked repository, fix it and pull-request the commit?

Tags: git, github, repository, git-fork

The scenario is like this:

I fork a repository on GitHub and open an issue in the forked one. It's issue #3 in the forked one.

I fixe it, make a commit "fixed #3" and I make a pull-request.

The problem: Someone else has already opened an issue in the original repository that is also #3.

1. After I made the pull request and someone accepted it: Will my commit message refer the my issue #3 or the one of the initial repository?
2. What's the common behavior on GitHub? Opening an issue in the initial repository or in the forked one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you submit a pull request, it will link to issue #3 in the original repo, the once you submitted the PR to. 
You should always open issues on the original repo, not the forked one, and use that numbering.